# How to send file inside custom array-list as Multipart in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, file, multipartform-data

I want to receive a file which is inside a custom array list. Let me explain in detail.

Below is my requestdto class for API call.

```
class Documents {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String moduleName; 
    @NotNull
    private String moduleId; 

    private List<DocumentsList> docList;
}
```

And below is DocumentList class which contains file

```
@Data
public class DocumentsList {
    private String name;
    private MultipartFile file;
    private String filePath;
    private String notes;
}
```

So, is it possible to access file from this request in Java Spring boot? Is it possible to achieve this using Multipart? I have tried to access file like this using many ways but I was not successful. Please let me know how can I solve this. Also, if there is any other way or some little changes in the requestDto can be made to solve this problem, I will not mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a zip file and sent the zip file

I use a DTO to send file with byte[]

```
public class FileDTO{
   private String fileName;
   private byte[] fileData;
}
```

You could use `Files.readAllBytes(yourFile.toPath())` to transforme your file to byte and put it in file dto

Comment: Do you mean that i need to make a zip file for each file and then send it as bytes?

Comment: @PriyankaAlachiya That's what I did in my application, I make a zip file and send it as bytes to my users